# Error : undefined reference to 'engOpen'

Tags: c++, windows, qt, 64-bit, qt-creator

Please, I'm looking for a solution to this problem 
`erreur : undefined reference to 'engOpen'` when I try to call mtlb function for c++

I'm working on win64 with QT creator.

Here is my .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick
CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\extern\include"
LIBS += -L "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\win64"

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LIBS += -L "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\win64"
```

You're only setting the lib path, you also have to point to the lib file:

```
LIBS += -L<path> -l<file without extension>
```

On Windows you can also just set the full path (with file), but the above format should work both with Unix and Windows. In your .pro you're mixing the Unix format and the Windows format.

Cf the Qt [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs).

Comment: the problem ws solved thnk's; but it will make another error :-1: erreur : cannot find C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\win64: Permission denied

Comment: @bz_benzait look at the file/dir permissions