# Error : undefined reference to 'engOpen' in Qt

Tags: c++, matlab, qt

I have tried to the following that says in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533749/error-undefined-reference-to-engopen). But I'm still having the error

I'm trying to connect Matlab with QT. I'm using Qt Creator 4.2 and QT 5.8. This is what I have in my .pro file.

```
QT       += core gui serialport axcontainer

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Totem_app
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

CONFIG+=c++11


win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2016b/extern/lib/win64/microsoft/' -llibmx
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2016b/extern/lib/win64/microsoft/' -llibmxd

INCLUDEPATH += 'C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2016b/extern/lib/win64/microsoft'
DEPENDPATH += 'C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2016b/extern/lib/win64/microsoft'
```

I have also included the head file.

```
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QtPlugin>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QThread>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\include\engine.h"
```

Could somebody help me with this problem? How could I include engine.h without providing the whole path directory? What am I doing wrong that I'm getting the undefined reference error? All help is highly appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

To include `engine.h` without the whole path, add another include path like this:
`INCLUDEPATH += 'C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2016b/extern/include/'`

The undefined reference, as explained in the post you linked, means you are missing a statement which specifies which library needs to be linked.

From [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/compiling-engine-applications-in-an-ide.html) I see that, although you have `libmx` already listed, you need to add `libeng` too.